# Having trouble making a table of plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

My problem is very simple. I'm trying to create an animation with a function's plot. Here is my code:

```
Azul := RGBColor["#19A3CD"]
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{(x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3, 0 <= x <= t}, {0, 
    x > t}}]
funcao := 
 Plot[f[x], {x, -0.6, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.006], 
  Background -> Black]

PlotSet := {PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], Azul}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.005]], 
  PlotRange -> {-0.2, 6}, 
  Ticks -> {{{1, 1, 0.04}, {2, 2, 0.04}, {3, 3, 0.04}, {4, 4, 
      0.04}, {5, 5, 0.05}}, {{1, 1, 0.04}, {2, 2, 0.04}, {3, 3, 
      0.04}, {4, 4, 0.04}, {5, 5, 0.04}, {6, 6, 0.04}}}, 
  TicksStyle -> 
   Directive[White, Bold, FontSize -> 48, FontColor -> White, 
    FontFamily -> "Montserrat"], ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}}
A := Show[funcao, Axes -> True, Evaluate@PlotSet]
GraficoAnimado = Table[A, {t, 0, 4.5, 0.1}]
```

And, at the beggining, the first plots looks ok, like this one:
[image]

But the nexts plots completely lose the pattern, like this one:
[image]

And, after some time, the plots continue ok.

[image]

Why on the earth is this happening?

Comment: Table localizes the variable t. Therefore, make A[t] a function of t. And also funcao[t] and f[x,t]

Comment: @DanielHuber I did it, and the problem is still there.
Could you try to run it in your Mathematica, and see what happens? Because I really think it is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is over complicated and buggy. Here is a simple way of writing what you want.

```
Azul = RGBColor["#19A3CD"];
ticks = {#, #, .04} & /@ Range[6];
f[x_] := (x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3
plot[t_] :=
  Plot[f[x], {x, -0.6, t},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Azul, Thickness[0.006]],
    Background -> Black,
    AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.005]],
    PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 5.1}, {-0.5, 6.2}},
    Ticks -> {Most @ ticks, ticks},
    TicksStyle -> Directive[White, Bold, 48, FontFamily -> "Montserrat"],
    ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}]
GraficoAnimado = Table[plot[t], {t, 0.5, 4.5, 0.1}];
```

The table of plots is too big to show in full, but here is what the first, 20th, and last plots look like.

```
Magnify[Column[GraficoAnimado[[{1, 20, -1}]], Spacings -> 5], .33]
```

[image: plots]

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The following gives you a `Manipulate` within which you can just run an animation.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Piecewise[{{(x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3, 0 <= x <= t}, {0, 
     x > t}}],
  {x, -0.6, 5},
  Axes -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], RGBColor["#19A3CD"]},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.005]],
  PlotRange -> {-0.2, 12},
  TicksStyle -> 
   Directive[White, Bold, FontSize -> 10, FontColor -> White, 
    FontFamily -> "Montserrat"], 
  ImageSize -> {1920/4, 1080/4}, Background -> Black
  ],
 {t, 0, 4.5, 0.1}
 ]
```

[image]

OR... Simply change the Head of the above to `Table`:

```
Table[
 Plot[
  Piecewise[{{(x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3, 0 <= x <= t}, {0, 
     x > t}}],
  {x, -0.6, 5},
  Axes -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], RGBColor["#19A3CD"]},
  AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.005]],
  PlotRange -> {-0.2, 12},
  TicksStyle -> 
   Directive[White, Bold, FontSize -> 10, FontColor -> White, 
    FontFamily -> "Montserrat"], 
  ImageSize -> {1920/4, 1080/4}, Background -> Black
  ],
 {t, 0, 4.5, 0.1}
 ]
```

Which will give you all of the individual `Plots`.

Comment: sorry, that's not what I need.
I know that I can do an animation with manipulation, but for now, I need the table with all the plots

Answer (score 0):

I am running MMA 12.0. The following code, using functions instead of expressions gives (I made the image size and font smaller because I do not have a XXL monitor).

```
Azul := RGBColor["#19A3CD"]
f[x_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{(x - 3)^3 + 2 (x - 3)^2 + 3, 0 <= x <= t}, {0, x > t}}]
funcao[t_] := 
 Plot[f[x, t], {x, -0.6, 5}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.006], 
  Background -> Black]

PlotSet := {PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.006], Azul}, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[White, Thickness[0.005]], 
  PlotRange -> {-0.2, 6}, 
  Ticks -> {{{1, 1, 0.04}, {2, 2, 0.04}, {3, 3, 0.04}, {4, 4, 
      0.04}, {5, 5, 0.05}}, {{1, 1, 0.04}, {2, 2, 0.04}, {3, 3, 
      0.04}, {4, 4, 0.04}, {5, 5, 0.04}, {6, 6, 0.04}}}, 
  TicksStyle -> 
   Directive[White, Bold, FontSize -> 4.8, FontColor -> White, 
    FontFamily -> "Montserrat"], ImageSize -> {192, 108}}
A[t_] := Show[funcao[t], Axes -> True, Evaluate@PlotSet]
GraficoAnimado = Table[A[t], {t, 0, 4.5, 0.1}]
```

[image]